# Can I override settings in a Gruntfile from a child directory?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm working on a plugin for Moodle that involves a lot of compiled JavaScript. Because of the complexity of the plugin, I'm writing it in TypeScript and compiling it with Webpack. This is all working fine.

However, Moodle has built-in Grunt tasks to help with JavaScript deployment, including uglifying the code. My compiled code is already minified, so this step isn't necessary. For some reason, putting the compiled code through the uglifier creates errors in the browser that aren't present with the non-uglified version. Because of this, I'm hoping to find some way to override the Grunt task.

The Grunt task is pretty simple; it uses a glob to find all javascript files in the various plugin folders in Moodle. I don't want to modify the top-level Gruntfile so that others can use this plugin without having to touch the core Moodle files. Is there a way I can create a Gruntfile (or some other flag) inside my plugin's directory that signals the parent Gruntfile to ignore my compiled file?

Unfortunately, removing my file from the watched folder is not an option. In development mode, Moodle serves the pre-compiled "src" script, so I need to keep the file there for development purposes (otherwise, I need to manually purge the cache each time I want to load the updated file).

Here's a general overview of what's happening:

Directory structure:

```
public (main Moodle directory)
  Gruntfile.js
  local
    my-plugin
      amd
        src
          my-webpack-compiled-plugin.js
        build
          my-webpack-compiled-plugin.min.js
```

`my-webpack-compiled-plugin.js` is the file output by Webpack (the file I don't want to be uglified)

The `Gruntfile.js` contains, amongst other things, this:

```
amd: {
   files: ['**/amd/src/**/*.js'],
   tasks: ['amd']
 }
```

The `amd` task is where the files get uglified.

So I'm hoping to find some way to exclude `local/my-plugin/amd/src/my-webpack-compiled-plugin.js` from getting to the `amd` task from *within* the `/local/my-plugin` directory to keep my plugin self-contained.